# How Can I resolve the mysql's syntax error?

Tags: mysql

### Premise · What I want to realize

I'm trying to execute the MySQL's "GRANT" command with MySQL client on bash, but I got a syntax error. it looks like that is no problem.

### testing environment

- My laptop

  - M2 MacBook Air
- MacOS

  - Ventura 13.6.4
- Google Compute Engine

  - Linux 6.1.0-18-cloud-amd64
- Debian

  - Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64
- MySQL

  - 8.0.36 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
- bash

  - BASH_COMPLETION_VERSINFO=(2 11)

### What I did

**1. Boot and execute on the MySQL client **

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 15
Server version: 8.0.36 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

### Problems occurring · Error messages

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
```

### that's all

I got the errors. What shoud I do?
Could you lend me a hand?

Comment: Why do you have `->`? It is not required. The system is telling you that this is where the error is.

Comment: The `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` part is not part of the user identification, remove it, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html

Comment: @Progman Thanks for your comment! I'll read it and trying to resolve the error.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because it made your code inconsistent with the reported error. Also, it invalidated the existing answer by Bib.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm sorry. I fixed wrong editing.

Comment: As progman stated previously, the `GRANT` statement doesn't have an `IDENTIFIED BY` clause. Just remove it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My daughter slept just now. So I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

The system is telling you that the error begins with `->`. If you look at any online help, you will see that nowhere does any help tell you that the command requires it.

Therefore, you should try:

```
GRANT ALL ON databasename.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

If you do happen to see `->` in any example, it means `command continuation`, you are not meant to enter it.

Comment: That won't work, because `GRANT` doesn't have an `IDENTIFIED BY` clause.

Comment: @Bib As you said, I tried to exec your answer, and I've gotten an another error. that is,
```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

~~

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO ‘username’@‘localhost’;
ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT
```

Why? I've logged in MySQL with root user..

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, well I can tell you it works with mariadb/mysql on Linux. It's all I have ever used.... `grant all on * to ed@host identified by 'somerandomtext';` work just fine.

Comment: I've removed `PRIVILEGES` from the answer.

Comment: @KKK You might want to avoid the " (double quotes) around your username and local host name.  See Bib's second comment up the list.

Comment: @Bib  I've resolved my problem. The user was never created in the first place. So After I created a user and exec that command again. The error was gone. Thanks for your support so much.